# Can't see my website background

Tags: html, css, macos, background

This is pretty weird. At work and on my iPhone I can see my website's background-image. However on my home computer (Mac) I can't see it. The background is just white. How can that be and how can I solve this weird issue?

Here's the styling:

```
body {
background-image: url('../gfx/background.png');
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
font-family: 'Lato', Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: is there any @media rule which might override the style?

Comment: Should be background-repeat: repeat not declare for y and x

Comment: I have tried it without the "background-repeat", but still same issue.